# Multiple rows, one query

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table, called `GPAs`:

```
name | semester | GPA
Joe    Winter     3.5
Joe    Spring     4.0
```

How can I return the following in one query?

```
name | gpaWinter | gpaSpring

Joe      3.5          4.0
```

Comment: First of all you have to normalize your database.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: That **is** a normalized schema, allowing you to easily do queries like *What is the average GPA across semesters?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, (SELECT GPA FROM GPAs WHERE name = t1.name AND semester = 'Winter') AS `gpaWinter`, (SELECT GPA FROM GPAs WHERE name = t1.name AND semester = 'Spring') AS `gpaSpring` FROM GPAs t1
```

But you should really not be doing this in SQL. The purpose of SQL is to retrieve the data; formatting it for display is the job of the application code.

Comment: @Pablo: I see no reference to a general case in the OP's question. In fact, I see only the details of a very specific case.

Comment: @RedFilter: agree. Nevertheless, I think he wants a general solution. I didn't downvoted you or Dan, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select name, 
    max(case when semester = 'Winter' then GPA end) as gpaWinter, 
    max(case when semester = 'Spring' then GPA end) as gpaSpring
from GPAs
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,GROUP_CONCAT(semester) AS semesters,GROUP_CONCAT(GPA) AS GPAs
FROM GPAs
GROUP BY name
```

This will return a row like:

```
name |   semesters   |  GPAs
Joe    Winter,Spring   3.5,4.0
```

Then you can parse semesters and GPAs.

You can also do something like `GROUP_CONCAT(semester,'=',GPA) as GPAs`, which will return:

```
name    |         GPAs
Joe       Winter=3.5,Spring=4.0
```

Then you can parse the GPAs row.

Comment: There is no reference to PHP in the question.

Comment: Sorry.  I removed the PHP reference.